# How to make NSCollectionView scroll together with other views

Tags: macos, nsview, collectionview, nscollectionview

I am looking for an answer to this problem, i want to make a view that contains nsscollectionview to display my products but also i want to display some buttons before. When i do that the buttons stay fixed when i scroll and collectionview scrolls. I am adding a picture of what i want 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWbzk.png

This is what i have now, this function creates all views

```
    let layout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = NSSize(width: 200, height: 300)
    layout.sectionInset = NSEdgeInsets(top: 100.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0
    layout.headerReferenceSize = NSSize(width: 100, height: 200)

    let collectionView = NSCollectionView()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    collectionView.isSelectable = true
    collectionView.setFrameSize(NSSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.backgroundViewScrollsWithContent = false;
    collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 100.0, y: 100.0, width:100.0, height:100.0)

    for i in 0...1 {
        for j in 0...3 {
            let rect = drawImage(row: CGFloat(i),col: CGFloat(j))
            collectionView.addSubview(rect)
        }
    }


    scrolllView.documentView = collectionView

    view.addSubview(scrolllView)
```

I assume example picture has some view at the top and then collectionview, and they scroll all together, whole window.

Does someone have an answer? Going nuts

Comment: How do the items in the image scroll? Which items are the buttons?

Comment: in particular image category items i assume are buttons (academic, art,,,,), and collectionViewItems are the books. I need when i scroll buttons should scroll too